# i want to make an applet display a letter every time i type and then move over a letter every time i press it

Tags: java, applet

the Code is  below. right now what it does is it constantly moves the letter and I only want it to move a over one character when I press the next letter instead of going over more. Also the x+=2 is another method I used and It also didn't work.. This is basically supposed to be a typing class... Please help.It also places all the letters in the same place.. I need it to place them one space apart and I can't press the same letter twice or it just moves the letter

```
public class Type_Client extends Applet implements KeyListener,Runnable
{
 boolean pickA,pickB,pickC,pickD,pickE,pickF,pickG,pickH,pickI,pickJ,pickK=false;
 boolean pickL,pickM,pickN,pickO,pickP,pickQ,pickR,pickS,pickT,pickU,pickV=false;
 boolean pickW,pickX,pickY,pickZ=false;
 boolean space=false;
 boolean run=true;
 int x=10;
 Type t1;
 Thread thr;
 public void init()
 {
     t1 = new Type();
     thr=new Thread(this);
     thr.start();
     addKeyListener(this);
 }
     public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k)
 {
 }
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k)
 {
 }
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k)
 {
     if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_A)
    {
        pickA=true;
        k.consume();

    }
     if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_B)
    {
        pickB=true;
        k.consume();
    }
     if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_C)
    {
        pickC=true;
        k.consume();
    }

     if(k.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)
    {
        space=true;
        k.consume();
        //Spce++;
    }
 }
  public void run()
 {
    while(run==true)
    {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        catch(Exception e){};
        repaint();
    }
}
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    if(pickA)
    {
        g.drawString(" a",x,10);

    }
    if(pickB)
    {
        g.drawString(" b",x,10);
        x++;
        x++;
    }
    if(pickC)
    {
        g.drawString(" c",x,10);
        x++;
        x++;
    }

    }
}
public void stop()
 {
 }
public void start()
{
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  The "Minimal" in [mcve] refers to the smallest amount of code that demonstrates the issue.  There is nothing in your cases from "G" to "Z" that is different from the "A" to "F" cases; they add nothing to the demonstration of your problem, and just make your code longer.  The "Complete" in [mcve] doesn't mean complete in the sense "from A to Z", but rather in the sense that code compiles. You can assume that we will assume you know how to copy-and-paste to complete the remaining cases in your project.  Please edit your question and trim down your example code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.

---

First, the infinite repaint loop:

```
public void run() {
    while(run==true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(20);
        }
        catch(Exception e) { };
        repaint();
    }
}
```

This is bad.  Remove it and the thread that starts it!

You only need to repaint the JFrame/JPanel/Applet when something changes in how the application will draw itself (or when the window geometry changes or the window is exposed, but the toolkit already handles all of those cases).

Ok, so when does something change?  Possibly any time you press a key.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
    // Your existing code here

    repaint();
}
```

Instead of repainting every 20ms you are now only repainting after a key is pressed.  This is probably still too often.  `Shift`, `Alt`, `Ctrl`, `Meta`, `Caps Lock` are all keys; if you press any of those, a repaint will be triggered despite your application not processing any of those keys.  But at least is a minor inefficiency.

---

Second, `x` is a field instead of a local paint variable.  It is initialized to `10` when the application starts, and incremented when paint is called.

```
g.drawString(" b",x,10);
```

Will draw the string `" b"` at (10,10) when the application is started and `VK_B` is pressed.  But the next time redraw is called (20ms later with your existing code), it will draw it at (12,10), and then (14, 10), and then (16, 10), and so on.

Instead, you probably want:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int x = 10;

    // Remainder of paint code ...
}
```

So that each time `paint` is called, it draws the same way (unless something changes in the applications state which causes paint to intentionally draw differently).

---

`drawString` uses pixel coordinates.  The letter "A" is more than 2 pixels wide in any legible font.  For example, in this ASCII art, the letters "A" and "B" are 5 "pixels" wide.  To leave a gap between the letters, "B" would need to be drawn *at least 6 pixels* to the right of "A".

```
  *    ****
 * *   *   *
*   *  ****
*****  *   *
*   *  *   *
*   *  ****

<-7px->
```

You can use [Graphics#getFontMetrics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/measuringtext.html) to determine how much to advance the position of each character based on the preceding characters, with a given font.

Or, you could use a constant advance of (say) 16 pixels.

```
private final static int ADVANCE = 16;

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    int x = 10;
    if (pickA) {
        g.drawString("a", x, 10);
        x += ADVANCE;
    }
    if (pickB) {
        g.drawString("b", x, 10);
        x += ADVANCE;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Or you could let the toolkit do the work for you, and draw a `String`.

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(27);

    if (pickA) {
        sb.append("a ");
    }
    if (pickB) {
        sb.append("b ");
    }
    // ... remainder cases ...

    g.drawString(sb.toString(), 10, 10);
}
```

---

Finally, your 26 `pick(Letter)` variables are *just plain awful*.  Consider a different method of recording which keys have been pressed.

Some options:

```
boolean picked [] = new boolean[26];     // boolean array (1 per letter)
Set<Integer> picked = new HashSet<>();   // A set of VK_ codes
Set<Character> picked = new HashSet<>(); // A set of characters
BitSet picked = new BitSet(26);          // A set of bits (1 per letter)
```

---

Here is the smallest working example I can make for you.  Adapt as needed.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Type_Client extends Applet {

    private String typed = "";

    private KeyAdapter adapter = new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            char ch = e.getKeyChar();
            if (ch >= ' ' && ch <= '~') {
                typed += ch;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void start() {
        addKeyListener(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        removeKeyListener(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawString(typed, 10, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: The code did work to type, but it types in order and I can't type the same letter twice. how shall I make it possible to type whatever I type and type the same letter as many times as I want?

Comment: Declare a field `String typed = "";` and add a letter to it in your `keyPressed` handler, and just `g.drawString(typed, 10, 10);` in the `paint` method.

Comment: That did not work, I tried and it still wouldn't type it.

Comment: It works fine.  Added example code showing the working applet.

Comment: The sample code did work, but when I tested the code you said to use it didn't work. but now it does.

Comment: Is it possible to make the backspace delete, and enter to go down one line

Comment: Of course it is possible.  But that isn't part of your question, as posted above, and should be asked as a new question, but only after you've tried to make it work yourself.  If this answer has been **helpful** to your posted question, you should upvote it (click grey up arrow to the left of answer at the top).  If it has **solved** your posted question, you should accept it (grey checkmark to left of answer, near top).  "Upvoting" increases the reputation of the answerer.  "Accepting" an answer will increase both the answerer's reputation as well as your own.